# How can I change the time interval for the generation of reports in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, tfs-reports

I installed **TFS 2010** just to test, and I have no experience with previous versions.

Now, the problem is that I have just created some **New Bugs** items but when I run the Report "*Bug Status*" they are not shown.

Are these reports created and cached at certain interval of time? Is there a setting that I can change to force the creation of a report?

Thank you in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to update the refresh frequency of the warehouse: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244694(VS.80).aspx

> 1. Log on to the application tier of Team Foundation Server.
> 2. Start Internet Explorer.
> 3. In the Internet Explorer Address box, type http://localhost:8080/Warehouse/v1.0/warehousecontroller.asmx.
> 4. On the ControllerService page, click ChangeSetting.
> 5. In the settingID box, type RunIntervalSeconds.
> 6. In the newValue box, type the new number of seconds, and then click Invoke.
> 7. This opens a confirmation web page which indicates that the RunIntervalSeconds setting was changed.

Comment: it's stange, I cannot access to the link you wrote me using IE. I receive the error "The resource cannot be found.". Probably there is some configuration missing in my installation

Comment: I found it! probably it has been changed with TFS2010. This is the correct link: http://localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I followed all steps, and I receive the message "The setting RunIntervalSeconds has been successfully changed to 120." but it seems that even with this change, the report is not updated. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: I tried set in the Report->Properties->Execution to **Do not cache temporary copies of this report** but nothing

Comment: (See answer below - had exactly the same issue, and adjusting the other settings fixed the issue).

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to change the IncrementalProcessingIntervalSeconds parameter (this is something we picked up in 2010).  The blog post below covers this pretty well, as we now have a few more settings to work with regardingreport refreshing:

http://estebanfg.blogspot.com/2011/02/controlling-data-warehouse-refresh-in.html