# Invoking TFS 2010 Web Services

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, tfs

I want to change the time interval between the generation of reports done on the TFS Warehouse and the TFS Cube, using the procedure from [this post on stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825706/how-can-i-change-the-time-interval-for-the-generation-of-reports-in-tfs-2010)

However, I do not seem to have the dialog and 'Invoke' command handy to be able to make changes to the TFS server, instead, I see this:

> POST
>   /tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx
>   HTTP/1.1 Host:  Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Length: length

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <ChangeSetting xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Controller/03">
      <settingId>string</settingId>
      <newValue>string</newValue>
    </ChangeSetting>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Is it that I do not have the necessary privileges to apply changes, or is it the settings of TFS that needs to be changes so I can invoke the web services? Anyways, I need to know how to invoke TFS web services.

**EDIT**
I found out that I do not have the required permissions to change the wanted parameters:

> Error: Access Denied: [...] needs the following permission(s) on the
>   resource Warehouse to perform this action: Administer Warehouse

Comment: Are you doing this from the TFS Server's computer ? I mean it won't work if you're not directly logged into the TFS Server (in RDP if you don't have access to the physical computer), preferably using the TFS Admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use two tools by Neno Loje to accomplish this scenario.

- http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/03/18/refresh-tfs-warehouse-cube-and-reports-on-demand.aspx
- http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/06/13/how-to-change-update-frequency-of-the-tfs-warehouse-cube.aspx

You do need to have the appropriate permissions though.